# JList of TextFields and JScrollPane doesn't show / Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a window that shows a dynamic list of textFields and 
if the number of textfields is large then I want to add a scroller.
I am using GridLayout.
The problem is that the panel I added the Jlist and scroller doesn't show anything, neither the list nor the scroller. Below you will find a part of my code.

```
                   //Label 
                JLabel numberOfTxt = new JLabel("Please enter the number in every TextField");
                int n = 11; //A random number of TextFields
                firstPanel.add(numberOfTxt, BorderLayout.NORTH); //Add label to panel

                JList textFieldList = new JList(); //Create a list of TextFields
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    //Add TextFields to list
                    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
                    textField.setBounds(0, 0, 6, 0);

                    textFieldList.add(textField);
                    System.out.println("textFieldList" + textFieldList);
                }


                textFieldList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                textFieldList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
                textFieldList.setVisibleRowCount(8);

                //Create scroller
                JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(textFieldList);
                listScroller.setBounds(0, 20, 600, 600);

                //Create layout for panel where the textfields will be added
                if (n % 2 != 0) {
                    n = n + 1;
                }
                thirdPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(n / 2, 2, 10, 6));
                thirdPanel.add(textFieldList);
                thirdPanel.setVisible(true);

                //ContentPane has BoxLayout
                contentPane.add(firstPanel);
                contentPane.add(thirdPanel);

                contentPane.repaint();
                window.pack();
            }
            window.revalidate();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Huh? You shouldn't be adding JTextFields to JLists as this doesn't make sense. What are you really trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

1. `JList` does not works this way. If you really need a `JList` of `TextFields` you should use `ListCellRenderer` (probably you don't, see p.3).
2. You adding `textFieldList` both to `listScroller` and `thirdPanel`.  Probably, you should replace `thirdPanel.add(textFieldList);` by `thirdPanel.add(listScroller);`.
3. `thirdPanel` uses `GridLayout`, but only one control is ever added to it. You should either add `TextField` directly to `thirdPanel` (easier way), or let the `JList` manage them.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick answer. Regarding 3. You suggest that I should let the thirdpanel layout null and add gridlayout to Jlist?

Comment: No. You should not add `TextField`s to `JList` in the first place. This is complete nonsense. Try to add `TextField`s to `thirdPanel` directly.